# Detect end of various lines who not stay fixed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do something in jquery and I can't find any solution. I have a website, it's structured like this:

```
<div class="Header"></div>
<div class="main"><?php include('content.html'); ?></div>
<div class="Footer"></div>
```

My include file is not an html list. It's just several elements in div like this:

```
<!-- LAST ELEMENT -->
<div class="element">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND ELEMENT -->
<div class="element">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
</div>

<!-- FIRST ELEMENT -->
<div class="element">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if I can put a link of my website to show you. If it's forbidden sorry, just delete it. There it is: [Web site](http://yuniru.com/eargasm/)

So you can see that there are so many link, in float left. And when it arrive is on the very right of the screen, next is below on the very left etc. And that makes several lines. When you click on one element, I would like to add (in jquery) a div with the screen's width, between the line of the element clicked and the next line. But it's not a html list it's just some div display in float left so each time I add one new element, each element move to the right and so each last elements of each lines change. It's why I don't know how to put my div between two lines. Cause I can't find the line where the clicked element is. If it was not a dynamic content who changes the lines would be always the same so I could just find the last element of the line and put my div after. But it's a dynamic content and my line always changes. You understand ?

I hope you understood me, I'm french and speaking about coding in English is not simple for me. Sorry if I made mistakes.

Comment: Hmmm...having a hard time following your logic...can you show the html of what you want it to look like after the element addition?

Comment: I don't know if I can put a link of my website to show you. If it's forbidden sorry, just delete it. There it is: [Web site](http://yuniru.com/eargasm/)

So you can see that there are so many link, in float left. And when it arrive is on the very right of the screen, next is below on the very left etc. And that makes several lines. I would like to add a div between two lines. The line of the clicked element and the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert an element after the element that the user has clicked on. If so, you can use jQuery's [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method:

```
$(".element").click(function(){
    $(this).after("<div style='clear:both;' class='element'>Hello World</div>");
});
```

In order for the div to take the screen's width you can use `'clear:both'`. You may also need to add additional css like `'width:100%'`.